# iperf3 doesn't find network bandwidth difference but curl does

Tags: networking, curl, latency

I have 1 client (A) and 2 servers (B & C). Servers were using different amounts of CPU with load balancing and i wanted to root cause it. I suspected it could be a network speed issue so I ran an iPerf3 test which i learned online was a common way to test network speed

the results were comparable for A-B and A-C

iPerf3 A-B:

```
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  4.77 GBytes  4.09 Gbits/sec  947             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  4.76 GBytes  4.09 Gbits/sec                  receiver
```

iPerf3 A-C:

```
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  5.28 GBytes  4.54 Gbits/sec   30             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  5.28 GBytes  4.54 Gbits/sec                  receiver
```

so I ruled out network as a possible cause but eventually I started debugging by curling the servers and noticed that there was a consistent difference in network transfer speeds

curl A-B:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  271k  100  263k  100  7748   847k  24877 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  870k
```

curl A-C:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  271k  100  263k  100  7748  1977k  58060 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 2041k
```

It turns out pod B was running on `r5a.12xlarge` which has network performance of 10Gbps whereas pod C was running on `r5b.24xlarge` which does 25Gbps.

I have two questions.

1. why was iPerf3 not able to find this difference in network bandwidth but curl could? did I not send enough data to reveal a difference in network bandwidth? but the curl only sends 271k as well.
2. why are the curl speeds set to 870 and 2041kbps? same with perf at 4.5Gbps. seems arbitrary.

I'm new to measuring network throughput and I'm really curious about why it's like this.